# how to store multiple data in odoo via postman form data

Tags: python, odoo

i have postman form data request like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMqcS.png)

product_char in multiple value insert to DB, this is my code

```
@http.route(['/api/post/petty_cash/'], type='http', auth="none", methods=['POST'], csrf=False)
@check_valid_token
def create_petty_cash(self, **rec):
    user_id = request.uid

    data_header = {
        'reference' : rec['reference'],
        'partner_id' : rec['partner_id'],
        # 'state' : 'manager_app',
        'request_by' : user_id,
        'date_requested' : fields.Date.today(),
        # 'attachment' : rec['attachment'],
    }
    petty_cash = request.env['petty.cash.app'].sudo().create(data_header)

    data_line = {
        'pety_cash_id' : petty_cash.id,
        'product_char' : rec['product_char']
    }
    petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().create(data_line)`
```

but the data product_char just 1 data stored to database , not 2 line data, how to stored multiple value into db using postman , i use odoo framework, Thanks

i try to loop code and not working, i expecting for **product_char** is stored 2 data into database

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Answer (score 2):

They way you are using to send data is not correct because there are two `product_char` in your request.

It would be great if you send `json` request because there can be multiple product_char then you can use loop while creating lines.

```
@http.route(['/api/post/petty_cash/'], type='http', auth="none", methods=['POST'], csrf=False)
@check_valid_token
def create_petty_cash(self, **rec):
    user_id = request.uid

    data_header = {
        'reference' : rec['reference'],
        'partner_id' : rec['partner_id'],
        'request_by' : user_id,
        'date_requested' : fields.Date.today(),
    }
    petty_cash = request.env['petty.cash.app'].sudo().create(data_header)

    for product in rec['products'] 
        data_line = {
            'pety_cash_id' : petty_cash.id,
            'product_char' : product['product_char'],
            'product_unit' : product['product_unit'],
        }
        petty_cash_line = request.env['petty.cash.line'].sudo().create(data_line)
```

**EDIT: For other fields like unit etc.**

First of all your request should be like this.

```
{
    'reference': 'API ODOO ke 16',
    'partner_id': 56819,
    'products': [
    {
        'product_char': 'Product 1',
        'product_unit': 'Product 1 Unit',
    },
    {
        'product_char': 'Product 2',
        'product_unit': 'Product 2 Unit',
    }]
}
```

Comment: and how to i want to add multiple product unit and same as product char ?

Comment: First of all you have to create unit field in line model and then while creating the record in line model which is `petty.cash.line` just pass this field. I update my answer and add sample request.

Comment: please give me example from code, i new coder

Comment: how to add looping for multiple price unit ?

Comment: 'product_char': product['product_char'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers - - -

error lijke this

Comment: if data json like above, how to i filled form data in postman ?

Comment: Then there will be no need to fill form data.